# Manipulating Form Values After jQuery.load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Good evening everyone,

I am currently trying to cleanup my inline JS and break it up into its own .js file, as well as breaking up some of my code into functions. Below I provide my code, I have an HTML file with an empty `div` named `#main`.  On document ready I want to call my `firstLoad` function. It simply calls `$("#main").load("login.php");`  Seems simple enough, however my next step is that on submit of the form I want to serialize the submitted data, turn to string and submit via post.  This for some reason will work if I hard code the form into the `index.php` file, but not if I use .load to fill in `#main`.  I can't figure out why this is, I am sure it's simple if someone could explain it  little that would be wonderful.  My code follows:

**UPDATE**
After more searching I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588309/jquery-load-and-trigger-function-after-new-content-loads-just-like-javascri) that says the following:

> As it turns out, the jquery .load() function is working flawlessly,
>   and I'm approaching this wrong.
>
> Once the .load() function completes successfully, it calls any
>   "callback" function included by the programmer, just like any other
>   jquery function that accepts a callback as one of its "arguments". *The
>   **.load() function is complete once it either errors or successfully
>   begins the HTML replacement** and loading of new content*, but that is
>   IT! The **content will then take however long it takes to load, but your
>   .load call is already complete before that**. Therefore, expecting the
>   callback to run after the .load content has loaded will only
>   disappoint you. ;)
>
> I hope others can learn from this just as I did, including those who
>   thought what I thought was the case. Proof: as stated in the jquery
>   ajax .load page, the callback is executed when the request completes,
>   not when the load completes. Eureka. Whoops.

Which leads to the follow up question, how can I manipulate the form after the load content has been added to the DOM?  This is surely a simple fix, but I am new to AJAX and could use a nudge in the right direction.  I notice adding a document(ready) within the login.php script works properly as it is added with the html, but it doesn't seem like the cleanest way of doing things, as I'm trying to keep out inline JS.  Any more advice?

**/UPDATE**

PHP/HTML

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $sessionNumber = session_id();
?>
<!doctype html>
<!-- Conditional comment for mobile ie7 blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/ -->
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]>    <html class="no-js iem7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MyMobile</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/h/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/m/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/l/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/l/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <header id="header">
        <img alt="Logo" src="img/logo.png" />
        <div id="blackHead">Please sign-in to continue</div>
    </header>
    <div id="main" role="main">

    </div>

    <footer id="footer">
        <div id="greyFoot">
            &copy; 2012 ACME<br />
            <pre id="result"></pre>
        </div>
    </footer>
  </div> <!--! end of #container -->


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/firstLoad.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php session_start();
    $sessionNumber = session_id();
?>


<!-- begin login form -->
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['sessionemail'])){ ?>
    <a href="logout.php" id="logout">Logout</a>
<?php }else { ?>

<form id="logForm" name="login" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="sessionemail">Email</label><br />
    <input id="sessionemail" type="email" name="sessionemail" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="150" required="true" value="" class="inputText" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required="true" value="" class="inputText" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" id="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionNumber; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subtocall" id="subtocall" value="g2.web.login.sub" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign-In" name="submit" class="submitBox" />

</form><!-- end login form -->
<?php } ?>
```

And finally, my JS/Jquery

firstLoad.js

```
//function serializes our object

(function($){
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);


//firstLoad function runs on document ready
//it loads the login form into the main div and slides
//the container down
(function($){

    $.fn.firstLoad = function(){
        return this.each(function() {
            $("#container").slideUp("slow", function(){
                $("#main").load('./login.php', function(){
                    $("#container").slideDown("slow", function(){
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

//logParse takes the loginResponse from the server
//changes from string to object, runs a check for authentication then
//manipulates the object dropping excess keys and adding new relevant ones for
//the intial to do list call
(function($){
    $.fn.logParse = function(xml){
        return this.each(function() {
            //parse the JSON login check string from the XML response
            var loginResponse = $(xml).find('string').text();
            //setup isBad variable for error check
            var isBad = false;
            //convert to JSON object from parsed string data
            loginResponse = $.parseJSON(loginResponse);
            //check if the sessionID is correct and user authenticated properly
            if((loginResponse.SESSIONID != "<?php echo $sessionNumber; ?>") || (loginResponse.ISAUTHENTICATED == 0)){isBad = true;}
            //if error flag is raised alert and bounce back to login
            if(isBad){
                alert("Unauthorized connection, please try again.");
            }
            //if there are no errors
            else{
                alert("so far so good!");
                //set up a new JSON object for to do list passback
                //and import the values from the lognResponse object
                //var todoPost =
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide screen for slidedown
     //$("#container").addClass("noShow");
    //allow cross domain scripts
    $.support.cors = true;
    //call firstLoad function to slide in the login prompt
    $("#main").firstLoad(function(){


        //create JSON object to store form input for AJAX POST
        //create submit listener
        $("#logForm").submit(function(){

            alert("inside submit");
            //parse form into formObj for data passing and manipulation
            var formObj = JSON.stringify($("form").serializeObject());
            //output initial formObj into result pane
            $("#result").text(formObj);
            $("#main").text("submitted: " + formObj);

            //AJAX POST call
            $.ajax({
                //type of communication
                type: "POST",
                //action for form
                url: "http://mydomain.com/JSONService.asmx/G2WebRequest",
                //data to be passed
                data: "request="+ formObj,
                //type of data passed in
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                //enable cross domain
                crossDomain: "true",
                //data type returned from webservice
                dataType: "xml",

                //if login POST was successful
                success: function(xml){
                    alert("post successful");
                    $.logParse(xml);

                },
                //if login POST failed
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }




            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JQuery.on()` solved this issue. Took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting up the listener on `$("#logForm")` before the login form is fully loaded into the DOM. This would explain why the login form works when hardcoded. You can test this by `alert($("#logForm").length);`- this will be zero if not found.

If this is the case you will need to ensure you wait until the login page is completely loaded before attempting to attach the listener. I would probably make `firstLoad` call a function once `load` completes.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think that's what I was doing? Using a Callback on load?  But this thread :

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588309/jquery-load-and-trigger-function-after-new-content-loads-just-like-javascri[/link]