# Triggering a function after an element has been fully loaded onto the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, jquery-trigger

Wondering if anyone can help because no one out there has given a solution this problem!

How do you wait for a dynamically loaded element (e.g. a specific div of another .html page) to first be fully loaded so that you can then, and only then, trigger a function?

`.load` obviously won't work as pointed out by the OP of this
[post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588309/jquery-load-and-trigger-function-after-new-content-loads-just-like-javascri)

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Update:
Some more info: I am using `.load` to load a div element from another page which contains data for use by Galleria (executed using `.load`'s callback). I am currently using `setTimeout` to ensure the div is loaded so that [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) doesn't load too quickly and empty. But I don't like this `setTimeout` business, it's too much of a patchwork solution.

Divs to be loaded:

```
<div id="source1" class="container">
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/7.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/7.jpg"/></a></div>
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/6.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/6.jpg"/></a></div>
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/5.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/5.jpg"/></a></div>
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/4.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/4.jpg"/></a></div>
</div>
<div id="source2" class="container">
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/3.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/3.jpg"/></a></div>
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/2.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/2.jpg"/></a></div>
 <div class="thumbnails"><a href="images/gallery/recent/1.jpg"><img src="images/navigation/recent/1.jpg"/></a></div>
</div>
```

Part of the Script:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var link = this.hash;
var ref = this.hash.replace("#", "") + ".html " + link;
var deferred2 = $.Deferred();
goLoad();
function goLoad(){
  switch(link){
    case "#recent":
     $("#recent").css("height", window.innerHeight);
     $("#recent").load(ref + " > *", null, goRecent());
    break;
  /*..other cases...*/
  }
};
function goRecent(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    deferred2.resolve();
    deferred2.done(doGallerySize, doGallery, goScroll)
    function doGallerySize(){
      $("#gallery").css("height", window.innerHeight);    
    }
    function doGallery(){
      Galleria.run("#galleria",{
        dataSource:"#source1, #source2",
        keepSource:true,
        responsive:true,
        thumbnails:false
      });
    }
    function goScroll(){
      $.smoothScroll({
          scrollTarget: link,
          afterScroll: function() {
            $(".stickynav").sticky({topSpacing:0});}
      });
    }
  }, 100);
}
});
```

Comment: generally you use callbacks of the methods that insert the elements. Provide some code that does the dynamic element insertions. If all you need is event binding, there are event delegation methods that can be used. Overall this question is far too vague

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to run your Javascript at the end of the .html page being loaded. I'm not sure exactly how you are loading your file, or I could help more.

Comment: How is the other div being loaded? If you show us the code that causes the div to be loaded, we can show you how to execute something after it finishes loading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if DOM element is fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916748/how-to-check-if-dom-element-is-fully-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Is .ready() what you are looking for?

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: this isn't an answer it is a comment and should be placed in comment block and answer deleted

Comment: @charlietfl I don't have enough rep to comment. For future reference, until I do have enough rep, how would I pose my suggestion to the OP?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for me, my script code is more short and simple, I append it to the body element, and have the special character escaped.

```
$('body').append('<script>var targetObj = $("#elementId"); var initialText = targetObj.text(); targetObj.text(initialText.replace(\/\\\|\.(\\w|\\W)+\/g, ""));<\/script>')
```

the code will be added at the bottom of the body, so you could ensure to access the dynamic loaded element in the dom.